# Running powershell or cmd on docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-for-windows, docker-exec, docker-desktop

I want to check the content of my docker container. I want to run a **powershell** or command prompt inside container so I can list directories.

This container image is hosting **ASP.NET Web API** application using ASP.net **4.6.1** framework.

[image]

I ran following commands:

1. `docker container ls - to list conatiners`
2. `docker exec -i -t a1da40af6b3c powershell`

But nothing happens (as shown in the image). Am i missing anything?

Comment: 1. Use `-it`, 2. Don't use ISE, try from normal powershell prompt

Comment: @GregorySuvalian: using normal powershell did the trick. Please add this as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISE hosted powershell does not work properly with a bunch of things. So try to do this either inside standalone powershell console or use VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the content of the docker container from a powershell or command prompt so that you can list directories, As shown in Screenshot.

Use Below command:
*docker exec -it <docker_container_name/id> /bin/sh*

This will take you inside your container. Then you can list out using 'ls' command.

Comment: This answer refers to linux, the OP was Windows

Comment: It also works on windows poweshell @LukeBriner