# Container encountered an error during CreateProcess while trying to powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-10

I managed to set up an asp.net core (2.2) app in a container on a Windows 10 machine and I could browse the application on a browser. However, I could not powershell on the container as described here: [Running powershell or cmd on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999890/running-powershell-or-cmd-on-docker-container).

```
docker exec -it 723b19acf1d6 powershell
```

Error I get in powershell:

```
container 723b19acf1d6a796812832dff82c2240af465d9100ade64d9ff95afce1a4267b encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(174)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7E0C2C00A: (caller: 00007FF7E0BFECEA) Exception(9) tid(580) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\ComputeSystemManager_ExecuteProcess\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app","Environment":{"ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://+:80","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```

[image]

The run command I used to setup the container:

```bsh
docker run -p 8081:443 -p 8080:80 -h myweb -v D:\Learn\DockerTrials\APITest\APITest:c:\temp apitest
```

Dockerfile:

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY certificate.ps1 .

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["APITest.csproj", "APITest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "APITest/APITest.csproj"
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet build "APITest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "APITest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APITest.dll"]
```

I am trying to set up https by running a powershell file following what is said here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2016/12/19/adding-https-support-to-individual-windows-containers-using-self-issued-certificates/

Comment: Since it is a dotnet.core image try `pwsh`(PowerShell core) instead of `powershell`

Comment: @Moerwald no difference still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Microsoft community forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8352b9b5-03ae-438c-80c7-6412631d490f/cant-run-powershell-command-in-nano-server-container-image-on-ws2019-datacenter?forum=windowscontainers):

> Microsoft removed powershell and other pieces from base nanoserver
>   image. You need to use image with built in powershell.

Comment: My intention was to set up https to asp.net core 2.2 app. Learning about the info you pointed out I like to stick with nano server. What would be your approach for https if not via powershell?

Comment: actually not sure but this link should help https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/aspnetcore-docker-https.md